# I'm not getting the expected response in fetch api

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

```
fetch('upload.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        body:formData
      }).then(response => {
        response.json();
      }).then(data => {
        console.log(data);
      }).catch(console.error);
```

I see `undefined` in the console and this is the output of response.json()

> Promise { "pending" }
>   ​
>   : "pending"
>   ​
>   : PromiseProto
>   ​​
>   catch: function catch()
>   ​​
>   constructor: function Promise()
>   ​​
>   finally: function finally()
>   ​​
>   then: function then()
>   ​​
>   Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Promise"
>   ​​
>   : Object { … }

I expect `{"response":"file uploaded"}`

Comment: You need to `return response.json()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never return response in your first then function

```
fetch('upload.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    body:formData
  }).then(response => {
    return response.json();
  }).then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  }).catch(console.error);
```

A nice reference point is:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch